# Which word is better to use in the sentence

Tags: word-choice

Which word is  it better to use in this phrase: “A few generations ago people with rheumatism used to carry hot potatos in their pockets as a means of ( cure / recovery)”. I’m confused and I  think both words are possible here. But I  have to choose  between “ cure “ and “ recovery “.

Comment: Can you edit your question to give some context of why you HAVE TO choose one of those two options?  Without that context, there is no reasonable way to answer this question, as I would not use either of those words by default.

Comment: ...But that said, given the option between them, I think that "recovery" is the better answer.  Disregarding the odd context of the sentence, "as a means of recovery" makes sense to me as a phrase, but "as a means of cure" does not.  In that situation I think you would just say "as a cure".

Comment: As for me , I would use  the word “ recovery” , but I don’t know why. I’m not a native speaker. 

Answer (score -1):

I would say that both are incorrect. The hot potatoes were not a permanent solution, therefore, not a "cure".

Furthermore, "recovery" is also inappropriate for the same reason. If you have to choose between the two, I would restructure the sentence as:

> “A few generations ago, people with rheumatism carried hot potatoes in their pockets as a temporary cure."